# Highchart dynamic creation - not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i am making a highchart drawing using dynamic function, it is not at all rending after the function called. later if i resize the window, it get rendering the data? any specific reason for this?

my function:

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function(){

    function randomData(len){
        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i<len;i++){
            arr.push(Math.random())
        }
        return arr;
    }

    var options = {
        chart:{
            renderTo:'graph',
            type:'line'
        },
        title:{
            text:null
        },
        xAxis: {
            plotBands: [{
                    from: 5,
                    to: 6,
                    color: 'yellow',
                    label: {
                            text: 'Yellow'
                    }
            }, {
                    from: 10,
                    to: 11,
                    color: 'green',
                    label: {
                            text: 'Green'
                    }
            }]
    },
        plotOptions:{
            series:{
                animation:false,
                dataLabels:{enabled:true,formatter:function(){return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y)}}
            }
        }
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    var i = 1, s1,s2,s3,s4;

    function createChart(){
        s1 = chart.addSeries({data:randomData(20),name:'Line'+i},false);
    }

    $('#create').click(function(){  createChart() });

})
```

Pls check my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/w46Sr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add chart.redraw();

```
function createChart(){
    s1 = chart.addSeries({data:randomData(20),name:'Line'+i},false);
    chart.redraw();
}
```

Comment: then how it's triggering while resizing the window?

Comment: I suppose they have window.resize handler and call redraw on it.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you set the set parameter of [addSeries](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#chart-object) as false.
In this case you have to set as true and it will redraw the chart after add the new serie.
For **one serie**.

```
chart.addSeries({data:randomData(20),name:'Line'+i},true);
```

Like the following example.
**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w46Sr/1/)**

Or if you want to add **more than one** serie in each click you just have to change one thing.

```
function createChart(seriesData){
    s1 = chart.addSeries(seriesData,false);
}

$('#create').click(function(){
    createChart(seriesData);
    chart.redraw();
});
```

You will add all of your series and after that redraw the chart, so you don't have to redraw your chart each time you add a new serie.