# Dynamically update pointStart and pointInterval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts to display daily stats, I want users to be able to select a date range.

```
function requestData(chart, from, to, group) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/stats/chart?from='+from+'&to='+to+'&group='+group,
        success: function(data) {
            chart.series[0].setData(data.data);
            chart.series[0].pointStart = data.start;
            chart.series[0].pointInterval = data.interval;
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

The js function does an ajax call and will return something like:-

```
{
"start":1358467200000,
"interval":86400000,
"data":[24,9,46,66,19,93,11,10,66,75,70,52,35,91,69,0,50,24,5,14,83,9,26,5,53,32,27,30,34,25,57,100]
}
```

How do I update the charts pointStart and pointInterval value?

Comment: What is the result of your current `success` function and what happens when you `console.log(data)` in it? Does the server set a mimetype in the header of the response?

Comment: The new plots are drawn but the axis labels don't change to the right date. I am passing back the data with a header type Content-type: application/json.

Comment: Okay so the object comes back and is properly identified and parsed as json - meaning this is almost certainly a highcharts issue.

Comment: Try to use dynamic methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549745/highchart-dynamic-creation-not-rendering-properly

Answer (score 6):

Since Highcharts 3, you can use [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update%28%29) :

```
chart.series[0].update({
    pointStart: data.start
    pointInterval: data.interval,
    data: data.data
}, false); // true if you want redraw
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited the original question to show a jsFiddle example that explains the issue, but I've got a working solution that I'll provide.

With my solution, the chart doesn't have to be completely reinitialized, but all series are removed and then the new series are added via the `Chart.addSeries()` method. I have a feeling that `Series.setData()` would be more efficient but I can't figure out how to get it working - maybe someone out there will!

My current solution (sucks): [jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mmuelle4/dg5Ks/2/)

So, in an answer to the original poster, you'd have to, as @jacobdalton's answer states, changing the json object to match the form of the `options` object, and then supply those objects to the `Chart.setData()` function.

Also, you may notice the `false` arguments `Series.remove(false)` and `Chart.addSeries(false)` - these arguments ensure that the chart is not rerendered each time these calls are made, and a single `Chart.redraw()` can be called afterwards to save on processing.

Answer (score 0):

`chart.series[0]` doesn't have an editable `pointStart` or a `pointInterval` property. You need to assign these through a dynamic method like `chart.series[0].setData()` and create a full `options` object (right now you're only sending the value `data.data` which is an acceptable parameter to the function but it can also take an object -- [check out the docs for setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29) and for [series options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions)).

I would suggest changing your json object to match the form of the `options` object:

```
{
    "pointStart":1358467200000,
    "pointInterval":86400000,
    "data":[24,9,46,66,19,93,11,10,66,75,70,52,35,91,69,0,50,24,5,14,83,9,26,5,53,32,27,30,34,25,57,100]
}
```

Then send the json object directly to `chart.series[0].setData(data)`.